# toString method deleting certain strings

Tags: java

[image: left is what it's supposed to print vs right which is what my program prints]

image if cant see above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dyTc.jpg

The above image on the left side is what it's supposed to print when the jar1 stone is == null vs the right side which is what my program prints.

I'm trying to create a toString method so that when jar1's stone in class ground is == null, it does not print anything in between brackets "[""]"
So in the code below I was able to get rid of stones name if == null, but was not able to get rid of the "#" and its weight which is seen above where it prints [#0] instead of just [].

How am I supposed to approach this toString problem?

I've tried using an if statement in the getName() method where if stone == null it returns ""; This made sense in my head but for the other methods which return an integer it really doesn't make sense to me.

```java
public class Ground
{
    private Jar jar1;
    private Jar jar2;
    private Jar jar3;
    private Player player;
    private Chest chest;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Ground
     */
   public Ground()
    {
      player = new Player();

      jar1 = new Jar(1, new Stone());
      jar2 = new Jar(2, new Stone());
      jar3 = new Jar(3, new Stone());

      chest = new Chest();
    }

   public boolean isChestUnlocked(){
    if (chest.jar1.getWeight() + chest.jar2.getWeight() * chest.jar3.getWeight() == chest.combination)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
    return player.getName() + "[]" + "(" + player.getPosition() + ")" + " [" + jar1.getName()+ "#" + jar1.getWeight() + "]" + "(" + jar1.getPosition() + ")"
    + " [" + jar2.getName() + "#" + jar2.getWeight() + "]" + "(" + jar2.getPosition() + ")"
    + " [" + jar3.getName() + "#" + jar3.getWeight() + "]" + "(" + jar3.getPosition() + ")" + 
    " /" + chest.combination + "\\" + "(" + chest.getPosition() + ")" ;

   }

}




public class Jar
{
    private int position;
    private Stone stone;

    public Jar()
    {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }

    public Jar(int initPos, Stone stone)
    {
        position = initPos;
        this.stone = stone;
    }

     public void move(int distance)
    {
       position = position + distance;
    }

    public void moveTo(Jar jar)
    {
        jar.stone = stone;
        stone = null;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
    if (stone == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return stone.getWeight();
    }

    public String getName() {
    if (stone == null){
        return "";
    }
    return stone.getName();
    }

    public int getPosition() {
     return position;
    }

}
```

Comment: That image is not readable.  Please don't post your output as images.  Copy and paste the text into the Question.

Comment: On an unrelated note, consider using the [null object pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern): create a stone that has zero weight and name `""`, and use that instead of `null`. Then you don't have to keep checking for null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a `toString()` in the `Jar` class as well. That could return `""` in case `stone == null` and `name # weight` otherwise. Then you can use `Jar.toString()` from `Ground.toString()`.